# Upgrading does not work due to unmet dependancies

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

```
bash: /home/pjotrs/.rvm/scripts/rvm: No such file or directory
bash: /home/pjotrs/.rvm/scripts/rvm: No such file or directory


E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
pjotrs@pjotrs-desktop:~$ sudo lsof /var/lib/dpkg/lock
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfs-fuse-daemon file system /home/pjotrs/.gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF     NODE NAME
update-ma 3440 root   56uW  REG    8,1        0 14942841 /var/lib/dpkg/lock
pjotrs@pjotrs-desktop:~$ sudo kill -TERM 3440
pjotrs@pjotrs-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc-l10n : Breaks: locales (< 2.21-1) but 2.13+git20120306-3 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

I am trying to install an upgrade. However it keeps coming up with the error above. How can I solve this?

Comment: To see what is holding the `/var` run `sudo fuser /var/lib/dpkg/lock`, then did u run `sudo apt-get -f install`?

Comment: I tried sudo apt-get -f install. This is what came up:                                                    pjotrs@pjotrs-desktop:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... failed.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc-l10n : Breaks: locales (< 2.21-1) but 2.13+git20120306-3 is installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
pjotrs@pjotrs-desktop:~$ What should i do next?

Comment: What is your version of Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0):

Well since I cannot comment, first upload your `sources.list` file. And for the time do this:

> $ sudo apt-get clean
>
> $ sudo apt-get update
>
> $ sudo apt-get upgrade